# How to stop Runnable thread activated by onScrollListener?-Android

Tags: android, for-loop, android-listview, runnable, arrays

I have edited my question.The reason why i edited my question is that no matter what i do thread was fetching all the items from the database.Retrieving few rows of data would not have been problem but if my dataset is large than it might force close my app if app takes much time to retrieve all the data and display it.

Now when my activity starts i retrieve just 5 items and display it on the listview.I accomplish this by using "loadMoreItems1" thread.
Than when the user scrolls down it retrieves 5 more items from the database and add it to the listview.I accomplish this task by thread "loadMoreItems"

By doing this i eliminated the possibility of app getting force close.But i ran into another problem and that it that after adding 5 items(using listMoreItems1 thread) initially in the list when i scroll down nothing happens the next 5items are not being added.Also when i scroll up after scrolling down i get "inder out of bound" errors/warnings.

Can anyone please suggest me how to tackle this problem?

I have posted the updated relevant code to this problem below:

Below is the code of my Runnables which is responsible for fetch data from JSONArray and updating listview when the activity starts:

```
// Runnable to load the items
private Runnable loadMoreListItems1 = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
        loadingMore = true;
        // Reset the array that holds the new items
        int lastItemDisplayedIndex = myquestionsResults.size();
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        db.getReadableDatabase();
        hm = db.getUserDetails();
        db.close();
        String un = hm.get("username");
        uf = new UserFunctions();
        JSONArray json = uf.getAllQuestions(un);
        for (int i = lastItemDisplayedIndex; i < lastItemDisplayedIndex + 5; i++) {
            try {
                ja = json.getJSONArray(i);
                id = ja.getString(0);
                userName = ja.getString(1);
                question = ja.getString(2);
                tag1 = ja.getString(3);
                tag2 = ja.getString(4);
                tag3 = ja.getString(5);
                posted_on = ja.getString(6);
                DataHolder qih = new DataHolder();
                qih.setId(id);
                qih.setUserName(userName);
                qih.setQuestion(question);
                qih.setTag1(tag1);
                qih.setTag2(tag2);
                qih.setTag3(tag3);
                qih.setQuestionPostedOn(posted_on);
                myquestionsResults.add(qih);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        // Done! now continue on the UI thread
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }
};
```

Below is the code of my Runnables which is responsible for fetch data from JSONArray and updating listview when user scrolls down:

```
// Runnable to load the items
private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
        loadingMore = true;
        // Reset the array that holds the new items
        int lastItemDisplayedIndex = myquestionsResults.size();
        System.out.println("bhalubhai");
        System.out.println(lastItemDisplayedIndex);
        qid = myquestionsResults.get(lastItemDisplayedIndex-1).getId();
        System.out.println(myquestionsResults.get(lastItemDisplayedIndex-1).getId());
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
        db.getReadableDatabase();
        hm = db.getUserDetails();
        db.close();
        String un = hm.get("username");
        uf = new UserFunctions();
        JSONArray json = uf.getAllQuestions2(un, qid);
        //int k = json.length();
        for (int i = lastItemDisplayedIndex; i < lastItemDisplayedIndex+5; i++) {
            try {
                ja = json.getJSONArray(i);
                id = ja.getString(0);
                userName = ja.getString(1);
                question = ja.getString(2);
                tag1 = ja.getString(3);
                tag2 = ja.getString(4);
                tag3 = ja.getString(5);
                posted_on = ja.getString(6);
                DataHolder qih = new DataHolder();
                qih.setId(id);
                qih.setUserName(userName);
                qih.setQuestion(question);
                qih.setTag1(tag1);
                qih.setTag2(tag2);
                qih.setTag3(tag3);
                qih.setQuestionPostedOn(posted_on);
                myquestionsResults.add(qih);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        // Done! now continue on the UI thread
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);
    }
};
```

Below is the code of Runnable "returnRes" which is used by both loadMoreItems and loadMoreItems1 to update ListView:

```
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Tell to the adapter that changes have been made, this will cause
        // the list to refresh
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // Done loading more.
            loadingMore = false;
    }
};
```

Below is the LogCat messages that i get when i scroll up after scrolling down:

```
09-09 02:22:38.348: W/System.err(276): org.json.JSONException: Index 5 out of range [0..5)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:455)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at com.dimecore.qq.Questions$1.run(Questions.java:190)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276): org.json.JSONException: Index 6 out of range [0..5)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:455)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at com.dimecore.qq.Questions$1.run(Questions.java:190)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276): org.json.JSONException: Index 7 out of range [0..5)
09-09 02:22:38.368: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:455)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at com.dimecore.qq.Questions$1.run(Questions.java:190)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276): org.json.JSONException: Index 8 out of range [0..5)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:455)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at com.dimecore.qq.Questions$1.run(Questions.java:190)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276): org.json.JSONException: Index 9 out of range [0..5)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.get(JSONArray.java:263)
09-09 02:22:38.378: W/System.err(276):  at org.json.JSONArray.getJSONArray(JSONArray.java:455)
09-09 02:22:38.388: W/System.err(276):  at com.dimecore.qq.Questions$1.run(Questions.java:190)
09-09 02:22:38.388: W/System.err(276):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
```

Code thats instantiate runnable:

```
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {


        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                loadingMore = false;
        }else{
                loadingMore = true;
            }
        }



        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            // what is the bottom item that is visible
            int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

            // is the bottom item visible & not loading more already ? Load
            // more !
            if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                thread.start();
            }
        }
    });

    // Load the first 5 items
    Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems1);
    thread.start()
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in a test to quit the `for` loop when `i > k`.

Comment: @techiServices thanks for the response.i tried to do this but seems like thread is still running and fetching the whole JSONArray array again and again.Now I dont get JSONArray out of bound exception though after doing this.

Comment: @Viking.  how are you initiating the execution of the `Runnable`?  Can you post the code?

Comment: @techiServices thank you for your response.i have updated my post and added the code which instantiate runnable.

Comment: @Viking.  are you sure the thread keeps being instantiated again and again?  if it is, i would suspect that `onScroll` is being called numerous times on a single scroll movement.  You may be better creating the thread once and just keep starting it if it is not already running.

Comment: @techiServices thank for the response.Can you please tell me in a bit detail on how can i accomplish that? Thank you!

Comment: @Viking.  which part, checking if the thread is being continuously started or creating the thread once?

Comment: @techiServices i was asking about creating thread once.Also i did this check of i>k in onScrollListener instead of doing it in Runnable.By doing this JSON Array is retrieved(one time in onScrollListener and one time in Runnable loadMoreItems) twice instead of again and again.But still this might cause problem is JSONArray is too big for e.g if JSONArray has 5000items this might cause force close on app :S

Comment: @Viking.  you may be better trying a different approach by using a `ListView` and a `CursorAdapter`.  I have to go now but will be back tomorrow.

Comment: @Viking.  to have one instance of the thread keep a class memmber variable to it along with a boolean to show a running status.  so when you start the thread set true and when thread comes to end set false.  also you may want to look at using `onScrollStateChanged` to help manage when the thread is run.

Comment: thanks for the response.i think i did try to do something similar but it didn't work.I'll redo it and post the code.I didnt do the onScrollStateChanged part though.Can you please tell me how it will help to stop the thread?

Comment: @Viking.  have a look at the API reference and look at the scroll states that get reported by `onScrollStateChanged`. You may be able to use them to help determine whether the thread should be started.  You shouldn't stop a thread, it should come to a graceful end by completing its code.

Comment: i tried to use onScrollStateChanged but didn't quite solve the problem.I have updated my code and approach to solve this problem.Please do check my updated code and pls tell me what might be going wrong? Thank You!